# When I click "review", will my own substandard posts appear?

Tags: support, review-queues

I have incessant anxiety over my own posts, and if substandard, whether they will appear anywhere. How am I to know? They may be presented to others and not me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, except for your own posts being involved in suggested edits, as you have access to see and review and have a binding review vote on whether a suggested edit is to be approved or rejected. Your own posts as any other task are not reviewable to you, even when they are in any queue. Therefore, they are not counted as a visible review item to you, even as audits. However, they may be presented to others, which you can figure out if you [have access to the Moderator Tools](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and therefore to study all the review tasks for presence of your own posts, or even to compose a [Data Stack Exchange query](http://data.stackexchange.com/lifehacks/query/249839/me-as-a-review-task?userId=137), which I've done for you:

```
SELECT t.Id AS [PostLink], t.ReviewTaskTypeId
FROM ReviewTasks t
  JOIN Posts p
  ON t.PostId = p.Id
WHERE p.OwnerUserId = 1961 -- This is you
ORDER BY t.ReviewTaskTypeId DESC, t.Id ASC
```

```
PostLink ReviewTaskTypeId 
-------- ---------------- 
2084     4                // First Post
2684     3                // Low Quality Posts
2342     1                // Suggested Edit
2782     1                // Suggested Edit

(4 row(s) returned)
```

Comment: That's good, but is Data.SE query always up to date?

Comment: @nicael No, the data dump in SEDE is updated every Monday.

Comment: Yes. So most of time the query will be just irrelevant. Those review tasks are not permanent things, you know :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you won't see your own posts in the review queues even if they were pushed there for some reason (as a result of flag, close vote, etc), unless you have a direct link to the review task (but even in this case you won't have an ability to review those tasks, of course).

Comment: I did not think so. I thought it would be fun to ask, anyway.

Comment: Eh, you can still see your own post(s) in the suggested edit queue (as well as act on those tasks), but only in there.

Comment: @Uni Only from http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activities&sort=suggestions. But if it was a tag suggestion and you have privilege to review tag suggestions, you'll see a number appear near the review link in the top bar, as if some suggested. When you click it, you'll find that the queue is empty... But it is not really related :D

Comment: @nicael: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cF3YL.png